# Spring @response body with defferent alphabet return bad results

Tags: java, spring, httpresponse

I have a spring method using the @responsebody annotation, when ever the resonse body has
Hebrew alphabet the response shown in the client is distorted. i changed the StringHttpMessageConverter charset to utf-8 but still the result is the same.

what can i do?

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,  
                    value  = {"/{accountID}/{containerID}/{objectID:.+}"})
    public @ResponseBody String createObject( @PathVariable String accountID, 
                                              @PathVariable String containerID, 
                                              @PathVariable String objectID, 
                                              HttpServletRequest   request, 
                                              HttpServletResponse  response)



<mvc:annotation-driven>
<!-- register custom converter that returns UTF-8 encoded response-body by defualt -->
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <constructor-arg index="0" name="defaultCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was the problem, the response content-length did not take into account the special chars size, once i added the extra space for the special chars the results on the client is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your `@RequestMapping` annotation should define attribute `produces`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,  
                value  = {"/{accountID}/{containerID}/{objectID:.+}"}, , 
                produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
```

otherwise it uses default encoding of your server that is not necessarily `UTF-8`.

Comment: i tried it too, still no luck. in addition i see that StringHttpMessageConverter uses utf-8 as its charset

Comment: First, make sure that your content is not broken before sending over HTTP. For example put something hard-coded. If it does not work too check what happens on client side. For example use Chrome developer tools to see HTTP headers sent by server.